# How to refresh textfield data in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, lifecycle

I've been trying to calculate a user typed leap year by pressing the submit button. If there is no value alert window is being shown but after tapping the "ok" button on alert window no matter which input I give to the textfield same alert window shows every time. (briefly: after alert window I cannot continue to use the app) I've tried `resignFirstResponder` method, `viewWillAppear` method after "create alert" method but none of the worked

```
@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = textField.text {
        if textField.text != nil {
            self.createAlert(titleField: "Error", messageField: "Please make sure you entered a year before tapping the submit button")
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                self.leapYear.calculateYear(year: Int(text)!, imageView: self.statusView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `textField.text` is never nil and you wrap the alert code inside the block which triggers when the textfield has a value ,   Use

```
if textField.text == "" { 
        self.createAlert(titleField: "Error", messageField: "Please make sure you entered a year before tapping the submit button") 
}else {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){ 
        self.leapYear.calculateYear(year: Int(self.textField.text!)!, imageView: self.statusView) 
    }
}
```

Comment: It was pretty straight forward after all  It worked after adding "self" before "textField.text!" Thank you so much 